# Creat dynamic menu in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am trying to create a side menu with all the categories (and later on sub menu with subcategories)

found this code online but I am not exactly sure what is going on

```
asp:Repeater id="MenuRepeater" runat="server">
                    <headertemplate>
                        <ul>
                    </headertemplate>
                        <itemtemplate>
                            <li></a></li>
                        </itemtemplate>
                    <footertemplate>
                        </ul>
                     </footertemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

what should I enter between the li tags and what code is needed using LINQ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ.  Please read the documentation on the Repeater control.

Answer (score 1):

Repeater is DataBound Control so it needs IDataSource to bind the data in/out it, you can write your LINQ query to get the menu from the database and call .ToList() method and bind it to the repeater control.

For example:

```
<asp:Repeater id="MenuRepeater" runat="server">
     <headertemplate>
           <ul>
     </headertemplate>
     <itemtemplate>
           <li><%# Bind("MenuItem") %></li>
     </itemtemplate>
     <footertemplate>
           </ul>
     </footertemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

in the code behind you'll create your IQueryable object and convert it to IList by calling .ToList() like this:

```
var query = from m in Context
select m.MenuItem;

MenuRepeater.DataSource = query.ToList();
MenuRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I am using three tier architecture and could not understand where exactly to put the MenuItem. Here is my code so far:

{BusinessLayer.Categories categories = new BusinessLayer.Categories();
MenuRepeater.DataSource = categories.getCategories().ToList();
            MenuRepeater.DataBind();}